# Neography and Neo4j dilemma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, neo4j, neography

I'm trying to implement a rails application with neo4j. For hosting I found that Heroku supports neo4j REST (public beta). Looking for gems I found neography and neo4j.

I started with neo4j and didn't find support for REST. Is it possible to work with REST? Is there any benefits to go with embedded database?

If I go with neography, can gems like devise be used in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you only need neography if you're using MRI Ruby. If you use jruby you don't need to use a restful server and according to the docs your neo4j queries will run faster. Devise will work fine with jruby, although you will find other gems don't work well with Neo4j (eg, declarative authorization or cancan) since they rely on ActiveRecord and Neo4j only satisfies ActiveModel.

If you do end up using jruby, I strongly recommend you use rvm to install it, and don't forget to add the '--1.9' flag when running ruby (or run "export JRUBY_OPTS='--1.9'") since jruby 1.6 defaults to ruby 1.8 which is not immediately compatible with Rails 3.

Sorry I can't answer your question about the REST client.

Answer (score 1):

in principle the advantage with the Neo4j embedded version is the great Rails3 and performance boost you get by not being forced to do REST. However, Heroku does not provide a permanent fiel system, which is why the Neo4j addon is operating over REST and thus Neography is a good choice for you.